# How to prevent a TableCursor with a ControlEditor from redrawing the previous cell when a selection is changed?

Tags: eclipse, swt, editor, jface

I'm working on Table that has TableCursor and a text editor. The problem is that after I select a cell the contents of the previous cell are drawn on top of the newly selected cell for a fraction of a second, and I want to prevent that from happening.

The following sample code exhibits the same problem:

http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/DemonstratesTableCursor.htm

If anyone wants to run the code, throw in these 3 lines before the TableCursor variable declaration and observe the problem as you select a different cell.

```
for (int i = 0; i < NUM; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < NUM; j++) {
        table.getItem(i).setText(j, Math.random() + "");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do the trick:

```
cursor.addListener(SWT.Paint, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
          cursor.setRedraw(false);
    }

});
cursor.addListener(SWT.Selection, new Listener()
{
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event)
    {
         event.display.asyncExec(new Runnable()
          {
              public void run()
              {
                  cursor.setRedraw(true);
              }
          });
    }           
});
```